# If G is a group of order 91, show that it can not have two subgroups of order 13

Tags: abstract-algebra

> If G is a group of order 91, show that it can not have two subgroups of order 13

My answer is: since $91=13 \cdot7$ and 7,13 are prime numbers, we have that $|H|$ must divided $|G|$. So G can have only 3 subgroups of orders 13, 7, or 1. Hence it can not have two subgroups of order 13.

Comment: Sylow's third theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You showed that the proper subgroups of $G$ can have only one of the three values. To prove what you want you need to use Sylow's Theorem. By the Third one we have that the number of subgroups of order 13, i.e. $n_{13}$ satisfies $n_{13} \equiv 1 \pmod {13}$, also $n_{13} \mid 7$. All this tells us that $n_{13} = 1$, so there is a unique group of order $13$